# Why is Universal reference being treated as R-Value reference?

Tags: c++, forwarding-reference

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A() {};
};

template <class T>
class Test
{
public:
    void func1(T&& t)
    {

    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    Test<A> o1;

    o1.func1(a); 

    return 0;
}
```

Following errors are seen on compilation

```
error C2664: 'void Test<A>::func1(T &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'A' to 'T &&'
note: You cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference
```

`o1` is obtained by instantiating template class Test with `"A"`. So the call `o1.func1(a)` should know that `void func1(T&& t)` should resolve to `void func1(A&& t)`

I thought `T&&` in `void func1(T&& t)` should be deduced as a universal reference or a forwarding reference because its from a template type parameter. Then why in the error above it says `"You cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference"`?

Am i missing some template magic here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I thought `T&&` in `void func1(T&& t)` should be deduced as a universal reference or a forwarding reference [...]

No. `t` in your example is not a universal reference. To be a universal reference it must be deduced from the call, but in your example `T` is just `A`. This is a universal reference:

```
template <class T>
class Test
{
public:
    template <typename X>
    void func1(X&& t)
    {

    }
};
```

---

The important detail is "deduced". In your example nothing is being deduced. Consider that `Test<A>` is equivalent to

```
class TestA
{
public:     
    void func1(A&& t)
    {

    }
};
```

Once you instantiated the class template, its method `func1` has argument of tpye `A&&`, not something else, ie there is nothing to be deduced anymore. Template argument deduction takes place when you do not explicitly state the template argument, as in

```
 template <typename T> void foo(T&& t) {};
 
 foo(1);
```

Comment: what if my example also has a class B and then i say Test<B> o2? In this case, T will be B also in addition to being A in previous statements

Comment: @Test sorry I don't understand what you mean. Renaming `A` to `B` wont change much

Comment: 463035818_is_not_a_number - Not renaming but also adding a new class called B

Comment: @Test the important detail is "deduced". In your code nothing is being deduced. You explicitly state that `T` is `A`, hence argument to `func1` is `A&&` and nothing else

Comment: @Test `Test<A>` and `Test<B>` would be two completely independent classes (both instantiated from the class template `Test`). In `Test<A>`, `T` would be substituted by `A`. In `Test<B>`, `T` would be substituted by `B`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number - So did you mean that a template parameter type will become normal R-value reference if not deduced? And if deduced it becomes Universal reference? And by deduction did you mean its type should be known at its point of usage/invocation?

Comment: @Test see update

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number - Refer to your statement "Template argument deduction takes place when you do not explicitly state the template argument, " . After this you gave an example of invoking as foo(1). Can't I invoke like this foo<int>(1) or foo<char>('c') ? Since here I am specifying the template argument, so it means deduction won't take place? But when I write foo(1) and foo('c') then deduction takes place? Can you clarify?

Comment: @Test yes. `foo<int>` is not a template. `foo<int>` has a `int&&` argument, no deduction happens